# Change message for location permission in UIWebView

Tags: ios, xamarin, uiwebview

I'm using web view for displaying RailWay map(it is modifaered open street map).
It is working, showing my current location, all fine.

My problem: I get 2 dialog for location permission.

First dialog is ok. I have description for it.

Second dialog show url and asks for permission, but i cant modify it text.

[image: Permission for CLLocationManager]
[image: I think web view shows it]
    .

I tried to publish this app to store, but it was rejected.
Reasone: "you need to show declaration why you are using location in this app" and second dialog in attachment

So is it possible to change text for second dialog? 
Or may be some advice?

Comment: You can add descriptive string in .plist file.

Comment: It is done, this description is in 1 dialog

Comment: NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription and NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription are in .plist

Comment: In info.plist add some description instead of that URL

Comment: I had NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUsageDescription instead of NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUseUsageDescription which is odd because from the docs it states that NSLocationAlwaysAndWhenInUsageDescription should be used.

Comment: Message in seccond dialog is not my and it is not from .plist. I dont have any idia how to change it

Comment: Could you Please show your code ?

Comment: I just create a Xamarin.Form WebView(under the hood it is just a UIWebView) and pass url https://www.openrailwaymap.org/mobile.php.

Answer (score 0):

**This is not an answer, just a debug for you.**

Actually you didn't ask the permission but the javascript that this webpage have. So whenever your webview loads the page, the javascript is called and it asked the permission.

Here is the screen image when i loaded this url in chrome.

[image]

Comment: And as I understode it is not possible to handle

Comment: @DmitryZinoviev yeah you can't handle it. If this site is your own then you can do.